# JQuery ajaxForm target doesn't work

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to upload an image from data using ajax. But i have a target problem. The target doesn't work. What i am missing here or what i am doing wrong here ? Anyone can help me in this regard ?

```
<form id="uploadimage" class="options-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='<?php echo $base_url;?>uploadimage.php'> 
 <label class="mup" for="upimg"></label>
 <input type="file" name="images" id="upimg" />
</form>
 <div class="targetit">
    <!--Target should be here-->
 </div>
```

Here is my ajax code

```
 $('body').on('change','#upimg', function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
      $("#uploadimage").ajaxForm({
         target: ".targetit",
         beforeSubmit: function() {
            // Do Something
         },
         success: function() {
            //Do something
         },
         error: function() {}
      }).submit();
   });
```

Not have any php problem. No error, no warning, no notice. I have just targetting problem here.

Comment: is success firing?

Comment: @charlietfl Yes everything is ok but not targetting. I just see jquery alert. Like [THIS](https://scontent-otp1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/18011059_448577202142111_4585090582628704312_n.jpg?oh=d993bfa998e2fa54f412b22eb2dbf34f&oe=5980A59A)

Comment: @charlietfl Could you give me an idea for a solution?

Comment: try moving the ajaxForm initialization out of the event handler...and just trigger submit inside the change handler. Create a demo that includes the plugin so we can test it

Comment: also try removing `success` ... been a very very long time since I used that plugin but could be that if `success` is defined, target doesn't get used

Comment: Also very easy nowadays to do ajax uploads without plugin. That wasn't the case 10 years ago when plugin was created